# "Expected a declaration" in merge sort implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm wrapping up a merge-sort function but I'm getting two "expected a declaration errors". Their locations are marked with a '~'. I've gone over it but I can't figure out what the problem is and I think fresh eyes are needed.

```
template <typename Comparable>
void merge(vector<Comparable> & a, int p, int q, int r)
{
std::vector<Comparable> tmp;

int y = p;
int first = p;
int sec = q + 1;

while ((first <= q) && (sec <= r)) {
    if (a[first] <= a[sec]) {
        tmp[i] = a[first];
        first++;
    }
    else {
        tmp[i] = a[sec];
        sec++;
    }
    y++;
}
if (first > q) {
    for (int x = sec; x <= end; x++) {
        tmp[i] = a[x];
        y++;
    }~
}
else {
    for (x = first; x <= q; x++) {
        tmp[i] = a[x];
        y++;
    }
}

a = tmp;
}~
```

Comment: I don't see any `~`s...

Comment: Had to recopy the code and forgot to put the '~' s back. they are at the end of the second if and at the end of the funct

Comment: I pasted this into Visual Studio and ran it, and it immediately told me you didn't declare `i`, `x`, and `end`. The `x` is probably a typo; you forgot the type in front of it in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loops have some issues. The scope of the variable `x` declared in the for loop has local scope to that for loop, yet you've tried to use it in the second for loop. If you want to re-use it, you'll have to declare it outside the for loop. Also, `i` and `end` isn't declared anywhere.

```
int x = 0; // declare x outside so both loops can use it
int end = 0; // assign it whatever you need it to be
int i = 0; // assign it whatever you need it to be

for (x = sec; x <= end; x++) {
    tmp[i] = a[x];
    y++;
}

for (x = first; x <= q; x++) {
    tmp[i] = a[x];
    y++;
}
```

You might want to declare i earlier as the first part of your code also uses it.

If you read your error messages they usually  would even tell you which variables are undeclared.